# SQL - Count grouped entries and then get the max values grouped by date

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I've got a sqlite table holding every played track in a row with played date/time
Now I will count the plays of all artists, grouped by day and then find the artist with the max playcount per day.
I used this Query

```
SELECT COUNT(ARTISTID) AS artistcount,
       ARTIST AS artistname,
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', playtime) AS day_played
FROM playcount
GROUP BY artistname, day_played
```

to get this result

```
"93"|"The Skygreen Leopards"|"2010-06-16"
"2" |"Arcade Fire"          |"2010-06-15"
"2" |"Dead Kennedys"        |"2010-06-15"
"2" |"Wolf People"          |"2010-06-15"
"3" |"16 Horsepower"        |"2010-06-15"
"3" |"Alela Diane"          |"2010-06-15"
"46"|"Motorama"             |"2010-06-15"
"1" |"Ariel Pink's Haunted" |"2010-06-14"
```

I tried then to query this virtual table but I always get false results in artistname.

```
SELECT MAX(artistcount), artistname , day_played 
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(ARTISTID) AS artistcount,
       ARTIST AS artistname,
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', playtime) AS day_played
FROM playcount
GROUP BY artistname
)
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',day_played)
```

result in this

```
"93"|"lilium"     |"2010-06-16"
"46"|"Wolf People"|"2010-06-15"
"30"|"of Montreal"|"2010-06-14"
```

but the artist name is false.
I think through the grouping by day, it just use the last artist, or so.
I tested stuff like INNER JOIN or GROUP BY ... HAVING in trial and error, I read examples of similar issues but always get lost in columnnames and stuff
(I am a bit burned out)

I hope someone can give me a hint. thanks m

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what's happening. I wouldn't even expect this query to run - since you've got "artistname" in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY, I'd expect the SQL engine you're working with to refuse to execute the query.

To resolve it, just add "artistname" to your GROUP BY in the outer query:

```
SELECT MAX(artistcount), artistname , day_played 
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(ARTISTID) AS artistcount,
ARTIST AS artistname,strftime('%Y-%m-%d', playtime) AS day_played
FROM playcount
GROUP BY artistname
)
GROUP BY artistname, strftime('%Y-%m-%d',day_played)
```

Comment: grouping again with artistname result in the first table output I've posted. Maybe I need a third Select and "JOIN" both results ^^.

Comment: SQLite, like MySQL, has this "feature" about the GROUP BY clause that you don't have to follow SQL standard & can omit columns...

Comment: That's a terrible "feature" because it leads to stuff like this. In any case, adding it to the GROUP BY should clean up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way after reading this:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/
But it feels stupid and maybe someone could give a hint how to optimize this.

I've created a sqlite **view** called *max_play_by_artist* which output all playcounts grouped by day_played

```
CREATE VIEW "max_play_by_artist"
AS
    SELECT COUNT(artistid) AS artistcount,
    artist AS artistname,
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d', playtime) AS day_played,
    artistid as id
    FROM playcount
    GROUP BY artistid,day_played
```

then I query the view with the following statement

```
SELECT b.artistcount, b.artistname, b.day_played, b.id
FROM 
(
    SELECT day_played, MAX(artistcount) as max_count
    FROM max_play_by_artist
    GROUP BY day_played
) AS a
INNER JOIN max_play_by_artist AS b
ON b.day_played = a.day_played
AND b.artistcount = a.max_count
```

this gives me the desired result.